# Find all the artist names with songs in all the possible mediatypes

Tags: mysql, join

I have a basic problem about create a query for listing artists with a condition of the artist have songs with all format type, the database have three table ( check ER diagram ).

> The Question is: Find all the artist names with songs in all the possible mediatypes

[image]

and the MediaType is listed here:

1. MPEG audio file
2. Protected AAC audio file
3. Protected MPEG-4 video file
   .
   .

I tried this, but I stuck in the where clause

```
SELECT a.[Name]
FROM track t INNER JOIN Album alb ON t.AlbumId = alb.AlbumId
 INNER JOIN Artist a ON alb.ArtistId = a.ArtistID
 INNER JOIN MediaType m ON t.MediaTypeId = m.MediaTypeId
WHERE
```

This is an overview of the SQL DDL statements:

```
CREATE TABLE MediaType ( MediaTypeId int(1) PRIMARY KEY, [Name] varchar(30) );
CREATE TABLE Artist(ArtistId int(3), [Name] varchar(100) ); -- LONG CHAR????
CREATE TABLE Album(AlbumId int(3) PRIMARY KEY, Title varchar(100), ArtistId int(3));
CREATE TABLE PlaylistTrack(TrackId int(4) PRIMARY KEY, [Name] varchar(220), AlbumId int(3), 
 MediaTypeId int(1), GenreId int(2), Composer varchar(220), Miliseconds int(12), Bytes int(12), UnitPrice decimal(8,2)); -- UnitPrice number
```

This is an overview of the data resumed:
Artist Table:

```
INSERT INTO `Artist` (`ArtistId`, `Name`) VALUES (1, N'AC/DC');
INSERT INTO `Artist` (`ArtistId`, `Name`) VALUES (2, N'Accept');
INSERT INTO `Artist` (`ArtistId`, `Name`) VALUES (3, N'Aerosmith');
INSERT INTO `Artist` (`ArtistId`, `Name`) VALUES (4, N'Alanis Morissette');
INSERT INTO `Artist` (`ArtistId`, `Name`) VALUES (5, N'Alice In Chains');
INSERT INTO `Artist` (`ArtistId`, `Name`) VALUES (6, N'Antônio Carlos Jobim');
INSERT INTO `Artist` (`ArtistId`, `Name`) VALUES (7, N'Apocalyptica');
INSERT INTO `Artist` (`ArtistId`, `Name`) VALUES (8, N'Audioslave');
INSERT INTO `Artist` (`ArtistId`, `Name`) VALUES (9, N'BackBeat');
INSERT INTO `Artist` (`ArtistId`, `Name`) VALUES (10, N'Billy Cobham');
.
.
```

Album Table:

```
INSERT INTO `Album` (`AlbumId`, `Title`, `ArtistId`) VALUES (1, N'For Those About To Rock We Salute You', 1);
INSERT INTO `Album` (`AlbumId`, `Title`, `ArtistId`) VALUES (2, N'Balls to the Wall', 2);
INSERT INTO `Album` (`AlbumId`, `Title`, `ArtistId`) VALUES (3, N'Restless and Wild', 2);
INSERT INTO `Album` (`AlbumId`, `Title`, `ArtistId`) VALUES (4, N'Let There Be Rock', 1);
.
.
```

Track Table:

```
INSERT INTO `Track` (`TrackId`, `Name`, `AlbumId`, `MediaTypeId`, `GenreId`, `Composer`, `Milliseconds`, `Bytes`, `UnitPrice`) VALUES (1, N'For Those About To Rock (We Salute You)', 1, 1, 1, N'Angus Young, Malcolm Young, Brian Johnson', 343719, 11170334, 0.99);
INSERT INTO `Track` (`TrackId`, `Name`, `AlbumId`, `MediaTypeId`, `GenreId`, `Milliseconds`, `Bytes`, `UnitPrice`) VALUES (2, N'Balls to the Wall', 2, 2, 1, 342562, 5510424, 0.99);
INSERT INTO `Track` (`TrackId`, `Name`, `AlbumId`, `MediaTypeId`, `GenreId`, `Composer`, `Milliseconds`, `Bytes`, `UnitPrice`) VALUES (3, N'Fast As a Shark', 3, 2, 1, N'F. Baltes, S. Kaufman, U. Dirkscneider & W. Hoffman', 230619, 3990994, 0.99);
INSERT INTO `Track` (`TrackId`, `Name`, `AlbumId`, `MediaTypeId`, `GenreId`, `Composer`, `Milliseconds`, `Bytes`, `UnitPrice`) VALUES (4, N'Restless and Wild', 3, 2, 1, N'F. Baltes, R.A. Smith-Diesel, S. Kaufman, U. Dirkscneider & W. Hoffman', 252051, 4331779, 0.99);
INSERT INTO `Track` (`TrackId`, `Name`, `AlbumId`, `MediaTypeId`, `GenreId`, `Composer`, `Milliseconds`, `Bytes`, `UnitPrice`) VALUES (5, N'Princess of the Dawn', 3, 2, 1, N'Deaffy & R.A. Smith-Diesel', 375418, 6290521, 0.99);
INSERT INTO `Track` (`TrackId`, `Name`, `AlbumId`, `MediaTypeId`, `GenreId`, `Composer`, `Milliseconds`, `Bytes`, `UnitPrice`) VALUES (6, N'Put The Finger On You', 1, 1, 1, N'Angus Young, Malcolm Young, Brian Johnson', 205662, 6713451, 0.99);
INSERT INTO `Track` (`TrackId`, `Name`, `AlbumId`, `MediaTypeId`, `GenreId`, `Composer`, `Milliseconds`, `Bytes`, `UnitPrice`) VALUES (7, N'Let''s Get It Up', 1, 1, 1, N'Angus Young, Malcolm Young, Brian Johnson', 233926, 7636561, 0.99);
.
.
```

MediaType Table:

```
INSERT INTO `MediaType` (`MediaTypeId`, `Name`) VALUES (1, N'MPEG audio file');
INSERT INTO `MediaType` (`MediaTypeId`, `Name`) VALUES (2, N'Protected AAC audio file');
INSERT INTO `MediaType` (`MediaTypeId`, `Name`) VALUES (3, N'Protected MPEG-4 video file');
INSERT INTO `MediaType` (`MediaTypeId`, `Name`) VALUES (4, N'Purchased AAC audio file');
INSERT INTO `MediaType` (`MediaTypeId`, `Name`) VALUES (5, N'AAC audio file');
```

My mysql not work at the moment for display an ER Diagram but I can draw with paint

I understand that my problem is related to join clause but I can figure out how to execute this query.

Comment: Unclear. In some code you use square brackets which are not distinguished by MySQL, but in another code you use backticks... please check your DBMS carefully.

Comment: For to solve you must group by an artist and count the amount of distinct mediatypes for the artist.

Comment: I am having problems with MySQL because is blocked in my country. I am trying to do something and when I fix this problem, execute the queries. I need to do this in MySQL in my last work I had to use Teamviewer to do something.

Comment: *I am having problems with MySQL because is blocked in my country.* This is not a problem, use any online fiddle. For example, https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=adbb57593b948249e7565893e76b84fd (all typos are fixed).

Comment: thk for the hint @Akina and for your information for execute MySQL code online but my database was too big for run in browser. I had to use teamviewer again. thk u for your hints help me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the credits to @Akina for hint me.

This query work:

```
SELECT a.Name
FROM Artist a 
INNER JOIN Album alb ON a.ArtistId = alb.ArtistId
INNER JOIN Track t ON alb.AlbumId = t.AlbumID
INNER JOIN MediaType m ON t.MediaTypeId = m.MediaTypeId
GROUP BY a.ArtistId, a.Name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT m.MediaTypeId) = 5
```